# A Monochrome Image Sequence

Tags: pattern, visual

<sub>*Inspired by [Conifers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/61486/conifers)' Fill the Image Sequence series, :)*</sub>

---

[image]

> What will be a suitable image to complete the sequence?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> [image]

Because

> The pictures are a long palindrome, "a man, a plan, a cat, a ham, a yak, a yam, a hat, a canal, *panama*."

Comment: Correct, very well done! :D

Comment: Or I guess you could just repeat image #7 - it seems to be the right kind of hat.